# Correlation between temperature and precipitable water in the tropical climate

Tags: meteorology, climate-change

Air temperature is known to correlate well with precipitable water at higher latitudes. What are the likely factors that degrade the correlation in the tropical monsoon climate?

Comment: Not sure why this question was downvoted. Welcome to ESSE

Comment: You are expected to show some effort to answer the question on your own. Especially for something that looks like a homework question.

Comment: @John - not sure this is a homework question.

Comment: @gansub I was the one who downvoted. I did so because I believe this question is unclear and very low quality. If the question seems like it should deserve elsewhere, please **edit the question so it's easier to understand what's being asked.**

Comment: @gansub okay, but my vote is locked until the post is edited, so I can't undownvote at the moment.

Comment: @E.Makama - please clarify if this is a homework or research question.